# requireJS, origin of the define statement

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm working on a large project that uses `Requirejs` for dependency management, specifically the convention is for every file to have this pattern:

```
define(['dependency1', 'dependency2'], function (dependency1, dependency2) {
    ... some code ...
});
```

now I'm investigating a failure where some file is trying to `require` a dependency that no longer exists.

I'm getting this error from `RequireJS`:

```
GET https://some-location/some-file.js net::ERR_ABORTED

Uncaught Error: Script error for: some-file
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at C (require.min.js:8)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.min.js:29)
    at HTMLScriptElement.nrWrapper (...)
```

How can I know which file contains the faulty dependency?
Simply searching the project files is not good enough since it is a large project that spans across multiple code bases.

Is there a way to make `RequireJS` tell me who asked for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of `requirejs` are you using? I'm using `2.3.2` and the error output provide more info, take a look:

```
GET http://localhost:9090/requirejs/js/dependency1.js net::ERR_ABORTED
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "home/dependency1",needed by: home/somefile
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1735)
```

Please, note that the part that says `needed by: home/somefile` is telling us the file that is `requiring` the failed dependency. This is the small local test I did.

**requirejs config**

```
require.config(
    {
        paths: {
            'home': './js'
        },
        callback: function() {
            require(['home/somefile'], function(a) {
                console.log(a);
            });
        }
    }
);
```

**./js/somefile.js**

```
define(['home/dependency1'], function (dependency1) {
    console.log(dependency1);
});
```

So, after getting the error `Uncaught Error: Script error for "home/dependency1",needed by: home/somefile`, we can say that the file `requiring` the failed dependency is `PATH_TO_OUR_PROJECT/js/somefile.js`. Remember that we need to pay attention to our `paths` in the `require` config.

You can play and test the [Global requirejs.onError function](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#requirejsonerror) but it won't give you more info than the regular `requirejs` output.

More info in [Handling Errors](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errors) from docs.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following Castro Roy's answer i made a test to verify this is indeed issue of requireJS version.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Require Test</title>
        <script data-main="main" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.2/require.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
requirejs(['someFile'], function(someFile) {
    console.log('main executing')
});
```

**someFile.js**

```
define(['someDependency'], function (someDependency) {
    console.log('someFile executing')
});
```

and someDependency.js obviously missing.

---

### Results:

using requireJs 2.1.20 (used in my project)

```
GET http://localhost:63342/playground-simple/someDependency.js net::ERR_ABORTED
Uncaught Error: Script error for: someDependency
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.min.js:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.min.js:1)
```

Then again using requireJs 2.3.2

```
GET http://localhost:63342/playground-simple/someDependency.js net::ERR_ABORTED
Uncaught Error: Script error for "someDependency", needed by: someFile
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1735)
```

---

So clearly Yes.
This is an issue of version and not some unique behavior of my project and this information is given in the error message for later versions of require.

sadly i was not able to find any documentation for this change